# Fusion Cores in the Corvega assembly plant?

Tags: fallout-4

I started a new game completed a couple of quests and collected four fusion cores and stashed them away for later.

I then started the mission to clear the Corvega assembly plant I cleared the outside of the plant with a sniper rifle filled my inventory with loot and ran back to drop it off.

Then I picked up a couple of fusion cores and got into my power armor to go finish the mission, shortly after this I realized I had three more fusion cores in my inventory than I should have.

I thought I had accidentally picked up all four of my spare fusion cores, so I ran back to put the spares back to find that all four were still in the stash.

My question is are there four fusion cores at the Corvega assembly plant that the wiki doesn't know about or did i accidentally find a way to duplicate fusion cores?

Comment: Sometimes, when I loot ammo boxes, there will be exactly 4 fusion cores to take. Possibly that happened and you didn't realize it?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is the problem? You cleared Corvega and found fusion cores? You should indicate which wiki you're talking about. I would assume Nukapedia: [Corvega Assembly Plant](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Corvega_assembly_plant). Are you looking at the notable loot list? That's not all the loot, and doesn't include anything randomly generated.

Comment: Fusion cores come under notable loot 4 fusion cores is very notable, and I didn't think fusion cores would be randomly generated or not so often at such a low level I didnt even go inside the plant only outside.I'm not complaining

Comment: In my Hard mode playthrough, my character is holding 150 fusion cores.  4 is **not** notable.  I stopped looting items at some point, so he could've had more.

Answer (score 8):

**Random drops are random.**

It sounds like maybe you looked at a list like [this](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Corvega_assembly_plant#Notable_loot) or [this](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_core#Locations).

These are just lists of the items that are fixed, and will appear in the same location every time. Things that are out on tables will always be there, for instance. Things that are in containers, however, are randomly generated.

To see this, save before entering a building. Enter the building, open a container, note the contents. Then, load your save, go back in, and open the same container. It should have different contents, most of the time.

So, you probably found some randomly generated fusion cores. They are sometimes in ammo boxes, in groups of four.

Answer (score 4):

I can verify Timmy Jim's observation in the comments. Furthermore, according to the [wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_core),

> In addition to fixed locations below, fusion cores may also spawn in groups of four in certain ammo boxes across the Commonwealth.

This supports our observations. You most likely found some and didn't notice when you picked them up (especially if you typically hit "Take All").

Comment: I hit take all all the time. They must have been randomly generated, thanks everyone

Comment: @user6178889 If you found either (or both) answer useful, upvote it. If you think one is best, mark it as accepted. There's no requirement that you mark one as accepted, and it's often recommended to wait a day or so before choosing one. You can change which one is accepted if a new answer shows up, and you can change up or downvotes if a post is edited.

Comment: It wont let me upvote because I'm new.

Comment: @user6178889 Oh, really? I assumed it would let you upvote answers to your own questions right away. You can upvote at 15, then: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: there we go I now have 16. Thanks again everyone.